# Creating a read() command in a custom function

Tags: r, function, csv, command-line-arguments

I'm still a rookie to the R world, in a very accelerated class with limited/no guidance.  My assignment is to build a custom function that reads in a specific .csv, and take some specific columns out to be analyzed.  Could anyone please offer some advice?  The "sample code" I was given looks like this:

```
AnnualLekSurvey=function(data.in,stat.year){
d1=subset(data.in,year==stat.year)
d2=d1[c("year","complex","tot_male")]
      attach(d2)}
```

So when it's complete and I run it, I should be able to say:

```
AnnualLekSurvey(gsg_lek,2006)
```

where "gsg_lek" is the name of the file I want to import, and 2006 is the values from the "year" column that I want to subset.  "complex" and "tot_male" will be the variable to be analyzed by "year", but I'm not worried about that code right now.

What I'm confused about is; how do I tell R that gsg_lek is a .csv file, and tell it to look in the proper directory for it when I run the custom function?

I saw one other vaguely similar example on here, and they had to use the if() and paste() commands to build the string of the file name - that seems like too much arbitrary work, unless I'm just being lazy...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if `data.in` is the full path to your csv file including extension, the first line of your function should be `d1 <- read.csv(data.in)` or similar. Do not use attach; instead just `return(d2)`. What do you mean "too much arbitrary work?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function like this:

```
AnnualLekSurvey <- function(csvFile, stat.year)
{
  d1 <- read.csv(paste("C:/",csvFile,".csv", sep=""),header=T, sep=",")  
  d2 <- subset(d1, year==stat.year)
  d2 <- d2[, c("year","complex","tot_male")]
  return(d2)
}
```

The argument 'csvFile' in the function is the basename of your csv file. In this particular example, this has to be in your C:/ folder. If your file is in some other folder, you have to change the "C:/" in the function to the folder where your csv file is located.

Running the function:

```
data <- AnnualLekSurvey("gsg_lek", "2006")
```

Note that the arguments has to be within the quotes. 'data' will now contain the columns year, complex and tot_male of gsg_lek.csv corresponding to the year 2006

Comment: What if they're on a linux machine? You might want to use `file.path` or `path.expand` instead of hard-coding a file path.

Comment: @technOslerphile the code looks like it ought to run, and I entered it exactly as you have it, except setting C:/ to where the file is (same as my working directory).  But when I run:
     data <- AnnualLekSurvey(gsg_lek, "2006")
I get this error:
Error in paste("C:/...exercise_dat", : object 'gsg_lek' not found 
- Since it is saying OBJECT gsg_lek not found, does that imply that it is trying to make gsg_lek an object before it has been read in to R?  Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the run-on comment above.  I tried "ctrl+k" and "5 spaces" to separate the code from the text, but neither worked...

Comment: Ah, my bad. Both the arguments has to be within the quotes. It is working for me.